# Overlap HTML border bottom

Tags: html, css, overlap

I'm making a Navigation bar. It has a border at the bottom. Now I want to give the active class a other color for the border. It should be in place of the navigation border, but it shows above it.

[image]

How can I put the blue line on the place of the green line under the active Home button and keep green at the rest?

CSS Code:
https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/9859d4e2a3983383bbb0

HTML Code:
https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/a09c4cb045eebeb89a4a

Comment: remove the border of nav bar?

Comment: @halkujabra I want to keep that. The blue line should overlap the green line only under the home button or whatever button with the active class. And the green line should stay at the rest, so under the complete nav-bar and under buttons without the active class

Comment: add a fiddle perhaps?

Comment: No way to say what you should change without seeing the CSS and HTML.

Comment: @Juhana Post updated with CSS and Navigation HTML code

Comment: So what do I do to get it working?

Comment: @Matt "margin-bottom" negatives is the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty simple.. You just need to set the `margin-bottom: -3px`.

Your CSS should look like this:

```
.navbar {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5cb85c;
    width: auto;
}

.active {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #5bc0de;
    margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4NLYZ/